# cause for SSH connection to work from A to B but not B to A

Tags: ssh

here is what I am experiencing

- RHEL 7.9 x86-64, latest {yum update} as of 10/1/2022; using the default `sshd_config` and `ssh_config` files per rhel-server-7.9-x86_64-dvd.iso installation; FIPS=1 as a kernel parameter.
- 1 gbps wired network, closed LAN, have admin access to switch
- `ssh serverB` from Server A = connection refused
- `ssh serverA` from Server B works, always works
- as soon as `FIPS mode initialized` happens and the `login:` prompt appears when ssh'ing from B to A, then an ssh from A to B will work
- subsequent ssh'es from A to B will work for some minutes after
- I come back an hour later, after having closed previous ssh connections, problem of connection refused when trying to ssh to server B again from A happens
- once a working SSH from A to B is established, trying to do a `scp 60gb.tar serverB:/backup` works for about 5 minutes, getting a solid 112 MB/sec the whole time, then files with `port 22 broken pipe, and packet_write_wait is mentioned.`  Don't know if this scp issue is related; the scp is not my main problem here but wanted to mention it; the scp problem is also repeatable.
- I have 10 other servers on same LAN, 4 of which do not experience this ssh connection refused problem nor have the scp problem.

what could cause this, how can I troubleshoot, how can I fix?

Comment: `Connection refused` nearly always means the server you're trying to ssh **into** does not have an ssh daemon listening on the port. The most likely reason is your `ServerB` does not have sshd running at all, but perhaps it is running but listening for connections on a different port number than the traditional port number 22.

Comment: Are all of these services configured identically? Have you inspected your firewall configuration on server B? Have you verified that `sshd` is running and listening for connections on server B when the problem is happening?

Comment: I've `setenforce 0` and `service firewalld stop` and problem persists; yes everything is configured identically.

Comment: Does `ss -tlnp` return a line showing that `sshd` is listening on port 22? Is it possible that your iptables/firewalld rules are kicking in after some time period? Try disabling to see if that helps. Or add extra logging to iptables to see when it is denying connections.